# Headers Token передавать в каждой запросе?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Добрый день дорогие друзья
Моя задача - передавать токен в в каждом запросе
Ну не передавать его вручную (думаю понятно написал =) )

Для этого я написал такой код в main.js

```
Vue.prototype.$http.interceptors.request.use(
    (config) => {
        const token = localStorage.getItem('token')

        if (token) {
            config.headers.Authorization = token
        }
        return config
    },
    (error => {
        return Promise.reject(error)
    })
)
```

Вот мой store

Как мне его переделать

```
const token = localStorage.getItem('retriewToken')

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    token: token || null
  },

  mutations: {
    retriewToken(state, token) { // мутация токена
      state.token = token
      state.isAuth = Boolean(token)
    }
  },

  actions: {
    retriewToken(context, credentials) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { //получаем токен по email/pass
        axios.post('web/login', {
          phone: credentials.phone,
          code: credentials.code
        })
          .then(response => {
          const token = response.data.result.token //беру токен - ключ
          localStorage.setItem('retriewToken', token)
          context.commit('retriewToken', token)
          resolve(response)
        })
      })
    }
  }
})
```

Пример запроса

```
created() {
  const headers = {
    'Content-type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': `Bearer ${this.token}`, //передача токена
  }
  axios.get('/mobile/user', {
    headers: headers
  })
    .then((response) => {
    this.client = response.data.result
    console.log("CLEINT data: ",this.client);
    this.clientInput = {...response.data.result}
  })
    .catch(e => {
    if (e.response.status === 401) {
      // alert("Авторизуйся ", e);
      localStorage.removeItem('retriewToken')
      this.$router.push({name: 'Home'})
    }
  });
}
```

Как правильно организовать headers, реактивно и по дефолту передавать headers token

Answer (score 1):

Я бы порекомендовал добавить Вам дополнительный уровень абстракции для Ваших запросов, а именно Service'ы. Данное изображение хорошо демонстрирует порядок движения ваших данных. Здесь Web API - это API вашего backend'а. Service Layer - это ваши сервисы и Storаge Layer - это VueX.

[image: Web API -> Service Layer -> Storage Layer]

#### Для чего нужна эта абстракция?

Она позволяет вашему приложению не знать о том откуда приходят данные, магические ворота из-за которых просто приходят данные. Никаких клиент-серверных отношений.

#### Как создаются сервисы?

Для начала мы можем создать базовый файл `Service.js` в отдельной папочке `service` в `src`.

> В отличии от store модулей, которые рекомендуется называть с маленькой буквы, файлы сервисов преимущественно содержат один класс конкретного сервиса, и называются идентично имени этого класса. Преимущества данного подхода Вы скоро увидите сами.

Наш файл `Service.js` будет содержать базовый класс сервиса.

> Для простоты, я использую тут `axios` но, Вы можете написать свою абстракцию, для клиента запросов и не беспокоиться о том, какая библиотека используется в Вашем случае.

```
import Axios from "axios";
  
export default class Service {
    static http = Axios;
}
```

Теперь мы можем написать свой первый сервис. И это будет сервис для аутентификации.

Создадим файл `AuthenticationService.js`.

```
import Service from "@/services/Service.js";

export class AuthenticationService extends Service {
  static login (login, password) {
    return this.http.post("", { login, password });
  }
}
```

#### Как это использовать?

Если Вы правильно пишите свое приложение, то все ваши запросы происходят исключительно через Vuex, а именно через экшены (actions). Именно их мы и рассмотрим. И так, представим что у нас есть именованный модуль authentication.

Тогда его actions будут выглядеть так:

```
actions: {
  async LOGIN ({ commit }, payload: { login, password }) {
    try {
      const { data } = await AuthenticationService.login(login, password);

      commit("SET_AUTHENTICATION", data);
    } catch (e) {
      throw new Error(e);
    }
  }
}
```

#### Много кода, не много разницы. Почему бы мне просто не делать запросы прямо в экшене?

Вероятнее всего вы делаете одни и те же запросы в разных местах в вашем проекте. Представьте что вывод этого метода внезапно изменился. Он отдает все те же данные просто иначе, например появилась дополнительная вложенность или изменилось название, например `login` изменился на `loginOrEmail`.

Логин это лишь пример, вероятнее всего он как раз используется лишь однажды, но давайте придумаем пример что бы наши действия обрели смысл.

У нас есть приложение [Pokédex](https://pokemon.fandom.com/ru/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81). У бэкенда есть метод `getPokemons` он реализует пагинацию и фильтр `relations`, который принимает id покемона и возвращает все формы развития этого покемона.

Один и тот же метод используется для получения всех покемонов, получения одного покемона, а так же при фильтрации всех покемонов по покемону.

Если бы мы делали запросы в экшенах, то при изменении этого метода на бэке нам бы пришлось искать все места использования этого метода в модулях стора и исправлять их, но имея сервис мы можем просто изменить его так, что бы данные которые нам приходят в ответе выглядели также, как они выглядели до изменения метода. То есть при изменении бэка, наш стор даже не заметит этого.

Comment: можно проще. ? ???

Comment: Что вы имеете в виду?