# Изменение данных в дочернем компоненте влечет изменение в родительском

Tags: vue.js, компоненты

Недавно начал изучать `Vue.js`, возможно просто не знаю чего-то, суть проблемы:

В `App.vue` имеется массив `folders: [],` который передается в дочерний компонент `Home.vue`. В `Home.vue`, в свою очередь, создается локальная копия данного массива: `localFolders: [...this.folders],` после чего над локальным массивом могут происходить некоторые действия(добавление, удаление, изменение элемента массива), для каждого из этих действий у меня есть дополнительный компонент, куда я передаю **локальный массив** из `Home.vue`, затем таким же образом в этих дочерних компонентах создаю локальные копии для возможности отката действий, однако тут возникает проблема, при изменении **локальной копии** массива в, скажем, `EditFolder.vue`, тут же происходят изменения и в локальном массиве `Home.vue`. Проблема даже в том, что по логике моей программы, измененные данные отправляются из `EditFolder.vue` в `Home.vue`, а потом и в `App.vue` **только после нажатия кнопки**, однако изменения в локальном массиве в `Home.vue` происходят еще **до нажатия** данной кнопки, то есть, сразу при изменении данных в `EditFolder.vue` они тут же изменяются и в `Home.vue`...

*Данные для `folders: [],` в `App.vue` приходят при загрузке страницы.*

Возможно что-то упускаю из-за неопытности, буду благодарен за помощь!

> App.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
   ...
    <router-view
      @edit_Folder="editFolder($event)"
      :folders="folders"
    />
   ...
  </div>
</template>

<script>
...

export default {
  ...
  data() {
      ...
      folders: [],
      ...
    };
  },
  methods: {
  ...
  async editFolder(changedFolderData) {
      const uid = await this.getUid();
      await firebase
        .database()
        .ref(
          `/users/${uid}/folders/${
            this.folders[changedFolderData.index].data.name
          }`
        )
        .remove();

      await firebase
        .database()
        .ref(`/users/${uid}/folders/${changedFolderData.folder.data.name}`)
        .set({ ...changedFolderData.folder });

      await this.getFolders();
    },
   ...
  },
</script>
```

> Home.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div
        v-for="(folder, index) in localFolders"
        :key="index"
     >
        ...
          <EditFolder
            :index="index"
            :folder="folder"
            @editFolder="edit_Folder($event, index)"
          />
        ...
     </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

...

export default {
   ...
   props: {
    folders: {
      type: Array,
      default: () => [],
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      ...
      localFolders: [...this.folders],
      ...
    };
  },
  methods: {
  ...
  edit_Folder(changedFolder, index) {
      // проверка на совпадение имени измененной папки
      if (
        this.localFolders.filter(
          (el, elIndex) =>
            elIndex != index && el.data.name === changedFolder.data.name
        ).length === 0
      ) {
        this.localFolders[index] = { ...changedFolder };
        changedFolder.data.show_settings = false;
        changedFolder.data.settings.showEditForm = false;
        this.$emit("edit_Folder", { folder: changedFolder, index });
      }
    },
  ...
  },
```

> EditFolder.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input
        v-model.trim="localFolder.data.name"
      />
    <button @click.left="editFolder">...</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

...

export default {
   ...
  props: {
    folder: Object,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      ...
      localFolder: { ...this.folder },
      ...
    };
  },
  methods: {
  ...
    editFolder() {
      if (this.localFolder.data.name) {
        this.$emit("editFolder", this.localFolder);
      }
    },
  ...
  },
```

Comment: Несмотря на то что создается каждый раз новый массив, все равно эти массивы хранят ссылки на одни и те же элементы. Если изменить свойства элемента внутри массива, при этом не изменяя состава массива, то это изменение будет видно и в других компонентах. Скопировав массив ты лишь "защищаешь" родительский массив от изменения состава массива, но никак не сами элементы в массиве.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Прежде всего хотелось бы заметить что это особенность JS, а не vue.*

Разберем проблему:

```js
// создаем оригинальный массив *ссылок* на объекты.
const originArray = [
  { id: 1, name: "Apple" },
  { id: 2, name: "Banana" },
  { id: 3, name: "Pineapple" },
  { id: 4, name: "Watermelon" }
];

// созадем копию массива *ссылок* на объекты
const oneLevelCopy = [...originArray];

// так как мы изменяем объект по той же самой ссылке, 
// он изменится в обоих массивах
oneLevelCopy[0].id = 0;

// но если мы пытаемся изменить массив, например
// добавив новое значение, оно добавится только 
// в новый массив, так как сами массивы разные
oneLevelCopy.push({ id: 5, name: "Kiwi" })
```

Что бы решить вашу проблему нужно создать **глубокую** копию массива, то есть массив и внутренняя вложенность должны быть скопированы.

Самый простой и не особо эффективный (по скорости) метод:

```js
const deepCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(originArray));
```

Вначале мы превращаем объект в строку, а затем из строки снова далем объектом, в таком случае у ссылок нет не единого шанса. Однако есть и ограничения. **В объекте нельзя использовать все что не может быть сериализовано**, например циклические ссылки.

*В вашем случае это скорее всего не проблема так как от Firebase данные однозначно приходят в JSON, а значит как минимум раз они уже были сериализованы.*

Но все же стоит это помнить. Я бы **порекомендовал** использовать более надежные средства например [lodash/cloneDeep](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.clonedeep).

*Еще один совет не относящийся к вопросу, не совершайте запросов и изменения данных во Vue, отведите ему роль средства отвечающего за отображения данных хранящихся и изменяемых в Vuex. А запросы вынесите в сервисы, и обращайтесь к ним только из Vuex. Чуть подробнее про это можно прочитать в [этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1201501/183429).*